# Display email id in shipping and billing address

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

I am working on Magento 1.9 version, I want to show email ID of user on billing and shipping address. I want to add variables in html of

> System->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration->Address
> Templates

but I didn't find variable to add email address.[image]

Use

> {{depend order.getBillingAddress().getEmail()}}
>
> {{var order.getBillingAddress().getEmail()}}
>
> {{/depend}}
>
> {{depend order.getCustomerEmail().getEmail()}}
>
> {{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}
>
> {{/depend}}

But still output is empty

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not provide email address variable in default address template. You can try below method.

**For Guest**

```
{{var order.getBillingAddress().getEmail()}}
```

**For Customer**

```
{{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}
```